# Flutter: have different authentication providers in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have different methods in my app to log in:

- Facebook
- Google
- Apple
- Email

For the question I'll focus on the first 2 ones. When the user logs in with Facebook the providers look like this:

[image]

That's fine but if I log out and log in again, this time with a new Google account but using same email, the providers look like this:

[image]

Now, if I log out and log in again with Facebook I face the `account-exists-with-different-credential` error. Something for which I have the logic prepared and show its provider login method, but this user should have both provider available and he should be able to log in with both methods.

This is my code:

```
Future facebookSignIn(BuildContext context) async {
    final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      final AccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken!;
      AuthCredential credential =
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);
      await _firebaseCredential(context, credential);
    }
  }

 Future googleSignIn(BuildContext context,
      [String? email, facebookCredential]) async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount googleUser;
      dynamic popup = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

      // cancelled login
      if (popup == null) {
        return null;
      }

      googleUser = popup;

      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      await _firebaseCredential(context, credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
      //   e,
      //   StackTrace.fromString("/googleSignIn"),
      //   reason: e.message,
      // );
      // return null;
    }
  }

 _firebaseCredential(BuildContext context, credential) async {
    try {
      User user =
          (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)).user!;
      // Provider.of<MyRents>(context, listen: false).updateUI();
      await firebaseProfile.updateUserData(context, user);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      // final error = e as FirebaseAuthException;
      if (error.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        String email = error.email!;
        // AuthCredential pendingCredential = e.credential;

        List<String> signInMethods =
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);

        // If the user has several sign-in methods,
        // the first method in the list will be the "recommended" method to use.
        if (signInMethods.first == 'google.com' ||
            signInMethods.first == 'facebook.com') {
          // TODO: fix facebook
          return await googleSignIn(context, email, credential);
        } else {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.message!)));
        }
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.message!)));
      }
    }
  }
```

Am I missing something?

```
flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.3.3
google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
```

Comment: You can link different authentication methods for the same Firebase user, [check here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/account-linking).

Comment: I don't understand this: "Complete the sign-in flow for the new authentication provider up to, but not including, calling one of the signInWith- methods". How am I suppose to log in the user if I don't use any signInWith method?

Comment: from this article: https://medium.com/@anusha.btech.2018/flutter-linking-accounts-in-firebase-with-different-authentication-providers-abe993ba4efe I read this information: "For linking accounts, the user must be signed in to the account with one of the authentication provider".
That's what confuses me. Following the scenario I mentioned, the user is not logged in between login with Facebook and Google and I don't know if the user wants to do this before login out from his current provider

Comment: So I have exactly same opinion as this: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/1318#issuecomment-616772012

Comment: I think the authentication completes when you create the `credential` with for example `EmailAuthProvider.credential(...)`. The official guide says you have to stop here without `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword`. But I personally haven't tried it, that's why I left only a comment and not an answer...

Comment: tried it already and it worked fine. The only problem is that, force the user to log in again with his previous provider in order to link it to the new one. Next time with any of them he can log in but the UX breaks a bit the first time, that's all. I'll comment the full solution when it's ready

Comment: from Google to Facebook I catch the error but nothing happens the other way around. Google replaces Facebook provider without any problem

Comment: apparently that's expected since gmail is a trusted provider and it does that despite we had another provider already: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/ms_NVQem_Cw/m/8g7BFk1IAAAJ

Comment: So Gmail has some kind of precedence because it is more trusted by the framework than Facebook for example?

Comment: I understand you can have other google accounts, not only gmail (company accounts for example use whatever@company.com) but since I was using gmail, Google doesn't care about any other provider. With Facebook this doesn't happen

Comment: Interesting things, thank yor for sharing with me.

Comment: added solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future googleSignIn(BuildContext context,
      [String? email, facebookCredential]) async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount googleUser;
      dynamic popup = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

      // cancelled login
      if (popup == null) {
        return null;
      }

      googleUser = popup;

      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      await _firebaseCredential(context, credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
      //   e,
      //   StackTrace.fromString("/googleSignIn"),
      //   reason: e.message,
      // );
      // return null;
    }
  }

Future facebookSignIn(BuildContext context) async {
    final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      final AccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken!;
      AuthCredential credential =
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);

      await _firebaseCredential(context, credential);
    }
  }

// other methods...

_firebaseCredential(BuildContext context, credential) async {
    try {
      User user =
          (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)).user!;
      await firebaseProfile.updateUserData(context, user);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      if (error.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        String email = error.email!;
        List<String> signInMethods =
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);
        // bool newUser = (signInMethods.length > 0) ? false : true;

        // If the user has several sign-in methods,
        // the first method in the list will be the "recommended" method to use.
        var user;
        switch (signInMethods.first) {
          case 'google.com':
            user = await googleSignIn(context, email, credential);
            break;
          case 'facebook.com':
            user = await facebookSignIn(context);
            break;
          case 'apple.com':
            user = await appleSignIn(context);
            break;
          case 'password':
            // since password is managed by user we force have email provider only
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text(translate('auth.signInMethods_password'))));
            break;
          // TODO: apple
        }
        await linkProvider(context, credential);
        return user;
      }

      return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.message!)));
    }
  }

  // just some extra error covering
  Future linkProvider(BuildContext context, credential) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.linkWithCredential(credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case "provider-already-linked":
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(translate('auth.provider_already_linked'))));
          break;
        case "invalid-credential":
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(content: Text(translate('auth.invalid_credential'))));
          break;
        case "credential-already-in-use":
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text(translate('auth.credential_already_in_use'))));
          break;
        default:
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(content: Text(translate('auth.something_happened'))));
      }
    }
  }
```

If you do Google -> Facebook it will look like this:

[image]

Other way around only Google will be present if your Google email is a trusted email (gmail). More info about that:
https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/ms_NVQem_Cw/m/8g7BFk1IAAAJ